# Deploy code with phing

Tags: php, synchronization, webdeploy, phing

I want to sync files from source folder to public folder with Phing but the problem is when I use

```
<copy todir="${libDir}">
        <fileset dir="${gitDir}">
            <include name="**"></include>
            <exclude name="public/**"/>
        </fileset>
</copy>
```

or

```
<filesync sourcedir="${gitDir}" destinationdir="${libDir}" verbose="true" checksum="true" />
```

the script doesn't remove the files from ${libDir} which already doesn't exist in ${gitDir}.
I don`t want first to remove the hole directory and after that to copy all files. It should works but it will take more time.
Do you know how I can sync the folders and remove the nonexistent files?

Answer (score 0):

I found the decision. I just use linux command for that:

```
<exec command="rsync -a --delete --exclude '.git' --exclude '.svn' ${gitDir} ${libDir}" checkreturn="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to slip into using 'exec' everywhere in Phing to use native OS tools.

Phing does have an rsync task  this has a 'delete' parameter.

> Syncs files or directories using the rsync command. Syncing can be
>   done on the same server or from/to a remote server.

```
<filesync  
  sourcedir="/var/www/development/project1"
  destinationdir="/var/www/html/project1"
  dryrun="true"
  itemizechanges="true"
  verbose="true"
  checksum="true"
  delete = "true" />
```

Link to the phing docs [FileSyncTask](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/FileSyncTask.html)